# Android Build error Cannot find resource: id closeButton

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When building android studio gives an error:

Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.

> Cannot find resource: id closeButton

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find resource: id closeButton

[XML view with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9veJ.png)

[Android studio version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUehb.png)

[Gradle (Project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lDI4.png)

[Settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9myzv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax for using id. try this one : `@+id/closeButton`